# How to use getSystemService in widget on android?

Tags: java, android, widget, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I want to use wake lock to keep screen on by clicking widget on desktop

code here:

```
final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "");
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

but it says `getSystemService` can not be used 
if it is not "extends activity".

please help

Comment: Have you hold to context?

Comment: First, you should learn OOP's basics... Method exists in the class. Next learn android's framework... Which class has this method and how get it instance in widget class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extend `AppWidgetProvider` all methods have a `Context` object passed in.

The `getSystemService` method is part of the `Context` class in Android, so you will be able to get it using the passed in context.

See: [Context and getSystemService on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService(java.lang.String))

**Example code:**

```
public class TestWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

The example code uses the onEnabled method as an example, but this also works in the other methods like `onDisabled`, `onUpdate`, `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use proper `context` for using `getSystemService` in a non-activity class or Widget.

```
final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);  //your context here
PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "");
mWakeLock.acquire();
```

And use camel case `Context` for `Context.POWER_SERVICE`

Hope this helps.